# How set header to PDF at the beginning and how set align center it

Tags: java, itext

In this picture I want set header of my pdf with library **itextpdf** (*version 7.0.2*), but as a result:

[image]

Code:

```
    String file = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/generator/Test.pdf";
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(file));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    float[] pointColumnWidths = {450, 200F};
    Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths);

    Text text1 = new Text("BLABLA BLABLA");
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
    text1.setFont(font);
    text1.setFontSize(20);
    text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE, 170, 20, 170, 20);
    text1.setFontColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
    paragraph1.add(text1);
    doc.add(paragraph1);


    Cell c1 = new Cell();
    c1.add("BlaBla:");
    c1.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c1);


    Cell c2 = new Cell();
    String number = "45875454";
    c2.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c2.add(number);
    c2.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c2);

    Cell c3 = new Cell();
    c3.add("BlaBla:");
    c3.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c3.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c3);


    Cell c4 = new Cell();
    String date = "06.04.2020";
    c4.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c4.add(date);
    c4.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c4);

    Cell c5 = new Cell();
    c5.add("BlaBla:");
    c5.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c5.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c5);


    Cell c6 = new Cell();
    String index = "56";
    c6.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c6.add(index);
    c6.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c6);

    Cell c7 = new Cell();
    c7.add("BlaBla:");
    c7.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c7.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c7);


    Cell c8 = new Cell();
    String blaBla = "06.04.2020";
    c8.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    c8.add(blaBla);
    c8.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
    table.addCell(c8);

    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Top Left"), 30, 800, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Top Right"), 550, 800, 0);
    }

    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("Bla Bla"), 110, 30, 0);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("page " + document.getPageNumber()), 550, 30, 0);
    }

}
```

iText provides `PdfPageEventHelper` class that has different event methods that is called while writing PDF. To add header and footer we need to create a class extending `PdfPageEventHelper` and override `onStartPage` and `onEndPage` methods. Register this class with PdfWriter.

Create an Event Class `HeaderFooterPageEvent` Extending `PdfPageEventHelper`
PdfPageEventHelper class has different event methods for PDF. It implements `PdfPageEvent` interface. Some event methods of `PdfPageEventHelper` are as below

```
onOpenDocument
onStartPage
onEndPage
onCloseDocument
onParagraph
onParagraphEnd
```

Comment: It's common practice on Stack Overflow that you don't just dump a code snippet, but also explain what it does and how and why. That would improve your answer.

Comment: Excellent. Now it's really useful for the next person who comes along. Upvoting!

Comment: One issue, though: the OP mentioned here uses itext 7 but your answer is for itext 5.